# Problems with np.where and lists with strings

Tags: python, string, list, numpy, if-statement

I have 3 lists, where one of them is:

```
x_axis = ["01-01", "01-02", "01-03"]
```

etc. Length of x_axis list is 377.

I also have a list:

```
y_axis = ["01-01","01-03","01-05"]
```

etc. Length of y_list is 167.

The third list corresponds to list x_axis with a specific number, where:

```
hour24 = ["50","0","99"]
```

etc. Length of hour24 is the same as x_axis, where dates in x_axis correspont with number in hour24.

What I want to do is to extract the numbers from hour24 list, that corresponds with dates in y_axis. That means that not all dates are going to be included. I want a new_hour24 list, which contains specific numbers that has the same dates as dates in y-axis. The  problem here is that x_axis list includes all dates, but y_axis list includes only some chosen dates.

What I tried to do:

I tried to extend y_axis list with zeros to contain the same length as x_axis:

```
for i in range(210):
        y_axis.append("0")
```

Once I had the same length, I tried using if/else and np.where numpy as:

```
new_hour24 = []

for i in range(0, len(x_axis)):
        if(np.where((x_axis[i]==y_axis[i]))):
             new_hour24.append(hour24[i])
        else:
             continue
```

However, this for some reason does not work, and my new list, new_hour24, contains all the original values, just as it jumped over the np.where fact and just appended all of the values no matter what.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can fix that?

***edit***

Expected output is a new_hour24 list with length 167. The numbers in list new_hour24 corresponds to dates in y_list.

Comment: can you post the expected output

Comment: I added an extra sentence in the end. Not sure how to explain it otherwise

Comment: is this the output for the example you posted `['50', '99']`?

Comment: Yes, those should be the first 2 outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.isin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
new_hour24 = hour24[np.isin(x_axis, y_axis)]
print(new_hour24)
```

**Output:**

```
['50' '99']
```

Comment: I tried that and then I recieve: 
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.  
I forgot to mention that x_list is not only numbers, but some places in the list it also says "MM.DD". While y_list is only numbers. I dont know if this is the problem

Comment: convert `hour24` to numpy array `hour24 = np.array(hour24)` it will work

Comment: Nice, @newtoprogramming. If the above answer was helpful, please accept it: it will be helpful for other members of the community to know that this was the solution to your problem. I also stands as a "thank you for your help" to the member that helped you (check at [this webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info).